# Add a view for expired invitations separate from pending ones

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

As an admin, I can invite people to my Team and see a report of who has accepted and which invitations are pending:

[image: Pending/Accepted/All]

Trouble is, when I look at Pending invitations, some have expired after 7 days of no response. The default sort for that list is by status, which does make finding actual pending and not-yet-expired invites easy enough. But it's odd to see a bunch of "Pending" invites that can't actually be accepted at this point. It also would be nice to see how many invitations had expired as a separate number in the tabs.

**Bonus feature request**: I can cancel pending and delete expired notifications from this view, but I can imagine wanting to resend them at some point in the future. I suppose I could copy and paste the emails, but it would be nicer to just press a button or follow a link instead. (And if we had that, I suspect it would be handy to have a way to select a sublist of invitations and act on them in bulk.)

Comment: this makes a ton of sense. thanks for this suggestion. adding it to our list!

Comment: can't we make Teams related tags with teams- prefix, like teams-admin? 
   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369567/please-use-teams-prefix-when-creating-teams-related-meta-tags